# Why do semiconductor companies not provide their datasheets publicly?

Tags: integrated-circuit, datasheet

Some semiconductor companies such as Broadcom and Microsemi do not publish the datasheets of some of their chips such as networking ones. It seems the companies do not provide the datasheets without an NDA. On the other hand, as far as I know the prerequisite for an NDA is an order for buying a high volume of chips (is it ture??)

So my questions are:

1- While some of the chips can be bought from electronic distributors, why do the companies not provide the datasheets?! What is the reason behind not publicly publishing the datasheets?

2- If I need a low volume of the chips, what should I do to access the datasheets?

Comment: THe same reason why NDA's exist.

Comment: They are scared of someone reverse engineering their product. My advice is to look elsewhere. I’ve had experience with Broadcom at one large company and their reluctance to disclose things even with NDAs (not everything is in the datasheet) resulted in us implementing our own comms stack. What type of functionality are you after?

Comment: @user110971 In my book, the datasheet of a chip does not provide considerable information for reverse engineering. I think there must be another important reason. I am looking for GPON controller and Ethernet switching chips. I cannot buy a lot of them so that I can sign an NDA. Even Chinese manufacturers do not provide the datasheets!

Comment: @M.H I don't agree with that. having worked for a large company and having been responsible for the datasheets.

Comment: Sometimes there is no good reason, just fear.   Company x does this maybe we should.  Management decides, dictates and it is game over.   The cost to clone is as much as the cost to create so millions to tens of millions of dollars, to cut in on someones margins by pennies or dollars.  In some cases the documents get leaked and the company doesnt care, in some cases the NDA holder simply publishes them.  And I have not seen those cloned at all and at least one is one of the supposedly competitive companies.

Comment: in some cases you might be a very successful company, and still not be worthy of buying from a particular vendor and thus no access to the docs.  not uncommon with these kinds of companies that sell ip you cannot reproduce the register set in your documentation even if yours is not closed leaving a gaping hole for your customers.

Comment: for some cases it is just silly as the product might have a linux driver and that is open source and you could clone something that responds to that register set/code base.  this is found with both chips and ip, in bootloaders/bsp and operating system drivers...

Comment: it is halfway between bogus and real.  Some ip is worth protecting, some is just management fear.  In either case if management values the ip at millions of dollars and your individual worth or small company worth is such that you dont have those kinds of assets laying around, what do you offer them as protection in case you or an employee leaks that information.  Your money has to pay for the clean up and damages so you have to have the assets in their mind and sign an agreement to use those assets (directly or implied).

Comment: the ndas may not state or otherwise include assets for cleanup, but think about the mindset.  is a college student really prepared and/or interested in protecting my asset?  What can I do to recover the damages if they dont?  The risk is all on me, same for a small company by my definition of small, some of these companies cant turn a profit unless they sell millions of units, so are only looking for folks that are capable of buying millions of units...

Comment: At the end of the day it is their property they can protect it however they choose, as a consumer you can choose to not play their games.  I have blacklisted companies that changed to open up everything just because they used to be closed source/closed document.

Comment: And what if you're a hobbyist who doesn't even have a company? Requiring an NDA is one thing, but they probably wouldn't even let me take that option.
It would be nice if there was some public repository where it was customary to share stuff whenever an NDA expired. (I guess under active NDA as well, in the unlikely event that a company is really willing to take that risk.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The companies you mention are not the only ones who require an NDA for product information and with good reason. I have had to work under NDA with TI (processors), Freescale (QorIQ series prior to full launch and now part of NXP), Vitesse (multi-gigabit crosspoint switch in the late 90s), Intel (networking devices), Broadcom (networking devices) and others.

A complex IC such as a networking device requires a *lot* of software support. The register map and detailed data on how to operate the device is part of the data sheet / reference manual. The functionality of the device at the deepest level (including specific pin functionality) is also part of the documentation. There is a great deal more, but this is an example.

If it were publicly available, a competitor could duplicate that map, internal functionality and pin functionality and make a device that is a drop-in replacement, (they would need to design a device which could be worth it for a large market) but that would reduce the selling price of the original part; this would make the investment required quite possibly exceed any return on the investment from sales.

Given the amount of money (*several million dollars*) that is invested in the design of such parts, it makes sense for the manufacturers to protect their product in such a way to protect their business model.

A market where a device is selling millions would be a very tempting target. Think SnapDragon parts used *extensively* in many designs. In the case of Broadcom, their advanced switching parts have some very advanced features that make them very attractive in networking gear as one example.

There are many parts that are sourced from multiple vendors and they are typically inexpensive for the good reason that they *are* available from numerous sources.

Note that the parts with a large market share would be tempting targets; this is the reason that a lot of data sheets *are* publicly available; the market is not large enough for a competitor to design a drop-in replacement.

Such things are standalone high performance ADCs (the market is growing but they do not sell in quantities of hundreds of thousands or more) and other high performance devices.

The ultimate reason is that the semiconductor vendors business model relies upon protecting their IP; for the ultimate in that arena, try getting your hands on the internal details of an Nvidia GPU; I worked with one (in a mission computer) and had access to the hardware manuals, but the software interfacing had to be done via a third party that works directly with them.

Each vendor has its own take on NDAs. Some may require a commitment to a minimum number of parts, others may not. I used Broadcom ethernet parts when I was at a startup that had the *potential* to use a lot of parts, although it ended up that we really did not use a huge amount.

The NDAs I have had varied widely; I even had a situation where a product line was bought up by a different company and parts that I had been able to get data for with no restrictions suddenly had to have an NDA; the opposite is also true - PLX required an NDA for a lot of their PCI express parts, but when they were bought by Avago (now part of Broadcom), the NDA requirement disappeared.

As noted in the comments, a *lot* of companies do not respond to emails from some domains (particularly educational, but in the past gmail, aol and the like were ignored).

Comment: Thanks @peter-smith. What are prerequisites of an NDA? Do I need to buy a lot of a chip to sign an NDA? or I can sign an NDA and get datasheets without buying a lot of them?

Comment: @M.H why not ask the company - they write and decide their NDA... They will tell you soon enough yes or no...

Comment: @SolarMike Actually they do not answer emails from a university domain! I am a student. I wanted to know your experience and then plan for future.

Comment: @M.H  depends on who and how you approach - many companies work with universities for research and development - even funding expensive equipment in the uni to get research done for them by faculty and top-flight students whose time, effort and skills they could not get otherwise.

Comment: @M.H Ask any professor(s) involved with your project, like your instructor or thesis supervisor, if they know anybody at the company. An inside contact can be a big help figuring out hoops to jump through to get an NDA.

Comment: You might get access by being a college student, might not.  As far as experience goes work with products that have documentation, the ti chips in the beaglebone family for example.  the allwinners docs are often leaked or sometimes allowed to be published.  be able to work backward from bsp, bootloader, or open source drivers.  you have a long long way to go before you are in a position where you would need to have to deal with this without mentors watching over you.